# Instance not refreshing after launch configuration update terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to update launch configuration user-data. But after apply, launch config is getting created and updated ASG. but running instance are still with old user-data. why so ?

Below are the launch config and ASG blocks.

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "BackEndWebLaunchConfig" {
        name_prefix             = "${var.component_name}-BackEndWebLaunchConfig"
        user_data               = file("user_data/${terraform.workspace}/vision-be-user-data.sh")
        image_id                = var.ASLCWEBAPPSAMI
        instance_type           = var.ASGWebAppsInstanceType
        key_name                = var.ssh_key_name
        security_groups         = [module.vpc.sgssh, aws_security_group.vision_backend_EC2SG.id]
        root_block_device  {
            volume_size         = var.EC2_EBS_SIZE
            volume_type         = "standard"
            encrypted           = true
        }
        #iam_instance_profile    = var.EC2_instance_profile
        associate_public_ip_address = false 
        lifecycle       { 
            create_before_destroy = true 
            }
        
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "vision_asg" {
        name                      = "${var.component_name}-BackEnd-ASG-TF"
        max_size                  = var.ASGWEBAPPSMaxSize
        min_size                  = var.ASGWEBAPPSMinSize
        health_check_grace_period = 300
        force_delete              = true
        health_check_type         = "ELB"
        desired_capacity          = var.ASGWEBAPPSDesiredSize
        launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.BackEndWebLaunchConfig.name
        target_group_arns         = [module.loadbalancer.visionalb_ext_tg_arn]  
        vpc_zone_identifier       = [module.vpc.PrivateSubnet0, module.vpc.PrivateSubnet1]
        termination_policies      = ["OldestInstance"]
        lifecycle       { 
            create_before_destroy = true 
            }
        tags                      = [
            {
                key                 = "Name"
                value               = "${var.component_name}-BackEndWebASG-TF"
                propagate_at_launch =  true
            },
            {
                key                 = "component"
                value               = var.component_name
                propagate_at_launch =  true
            },
                        {
                key                 = "tier"
                value               = "web"
                propagate_at_launch =  true
            }
            ]
        depends_on = [
          aws_sns_topic.BackEndSNSTopic, aws_launch_configuration.BackEndWebLaunchConfig
        ]

}
```

After apply, new launch config is creating but ec2 machines are not refreshing.

```
aws_autoscaling_group.vision_asg: Refreshing state... [id=BackEnd-ASG-TF]
aws_autoscaling_policy.BEWebScaleUpPolicy: Refreshing state... [id=BEWebScaleUpPolicy]
aws_autoscaling_notification.vision_asg_notification: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:193676128801:BackEndApplication-TF]
aws_autoscaling_policy.BEWebScaleDownPolicy: Refreshing state... [id=BEWebScaleDownPolicy]
aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.BEScaleDownNotifyAlarm: Refreshing state... [id=BEScaleDownNotifyAlarm]
aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.ScaleUPNotifyAlarm: Refreshing state... [id=ScaleUPNotifyAlarm]
aws_launch_configuration.BackEndWebLaunchConfig: Creating...
aws_launch_configuration.BackEndWebLaunchConfig: Creation complete after 8s [id=BackEndWebLaunchConfig20210508105416185400000001]
aws_autoscaling_group.vision_asg: Modifying... [id=BackEnd-ASG-TF]
aws_autoscaling_group.vision_asg: Modifications complete after 4s [id=BackEnd-ASG-TF]
aws_launch_configuration.BackEndWebLaunchConfig (2530c36e): Destroying... [id=BackEndWebLaunchConfig20210508103324724600000001]
aws_launch_configuration.BackEndWebLaunchConfig: Destruction complete after 2s

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 1 changed, 1 destroyed.

Outputs:
```

Please let me know, if i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question is answered in the AWS documentation on [Changing the launch configuration for an Auto Scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/change-launch-config.html), which says:

> After you change the launch configuration for an Auto Scaling group, any new instances are launched using the new configuration options, but existing instances are not affected. To update the existing instances, terminate them so that they are replaced by your Auto Scaling group, or allow automatic scaling to gradually replace older instances with newer instances based on your termination policies.

To perform the instance refresh during `terraform apply`, you could do the following:

1. Upgrade your Terraform AWS Provider to at least 3.22.0.
2. Add an `instance_refresh` block to your `aws_autoscaling_group` resource. Here is an example, provided from their docs:

```
 instance_refresh {
    strategy = "Rolling"
    preferences {
      // You probably want more than 50% healthy depending on how much headroom you have
      min_healthy_percentage = 50
    }
    // Depending the triggers you wish to configure, you may not want to include this
    triggers = ["tag"]
  }
```

The [associated documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group#instance_refresh) states:

> A refresh will always be triggered by a change in any of launch_configuration, launch_template, or mixed_instances_policy.

One final note to think about. Depending on your use case, you may prefer to control the cadence of instance restarts separately from `terraform apply`. In some projects, we have avoided this so that we can run `terraform apply` in CI/CD with less apprehension about swapping the machines running our production workloads at an inopportune time. Be aware that `terraform` can currently trigger the instance refresh, but it will not monitor the instance refresh for success or failure.

Comment: By defaul launch config update itself trigger a instance refresh, why i need to create explicitly.  after instance refresh this msg i got.  Warning: 'launch_configuration' always triggers an instance refresh

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my answer a change to your `launch_configuration` will always trigger an instance refresh if you have configured an `instance_refresh` block in your `aws_autoscaling_group`. You might receive this warning if the launch configuration does not remain consistent between terraform apply operations. For example, I noticed that you use a shell script to configure your `user_data`. I could see that making an inconsistent configuration that will trigger more instance refreshes than you want. You may want to pull that out into a separate question.

Comment: Not sure if you are getting me, when i add instance refresh block. terraform warns me, that by default update launch configuration triggers instance refresh, please remove your instance refresh trigger.

Comment: For anybody landing here in late 2022, launch template changes do not appear to trigger instance refresh, even if you explicitly reference the launch template version number (as opposed to "latest").  See this github issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23274

Comment: Thanks for your answer - been stuck on that issue since yesterday! You just made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a launch_template, you need to explicity put in the launch template version for the instance refresh to kick in.
You can use aws_launch_template.<template_resource>.latest_version instead of "$Latest" as version to make things work.

If in case your block in the auto_scaling_group looks like this:

```
launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.ec2-template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
```

Replace version with aws_launch_template.<template_resource>.latest_version and the instance refresh would get triggered upon modification of launch template.