# Autorollback during Autoscaling instance refresh through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to configure auto rollback during instance refresh for an autoscaling group but running into the following error.

> Error: starting Auto Scaling Group (terraform-20230820171958436000000003) instance refresh: ValidationError: The request isn’t valid. The AutoRollback parameter cannot be set to true when the DesiredConfiguration parameter is empty. Set AutoRollback to false or specify a desired configuration and try again.

Here is my terraform configuration file (main.tf):

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  availability_zones = ["us-west-2a"]
  desired_capacity   = 1
  max_size           = 2
  min_size           = 1

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.example.id
    version = aws_launch_template.example.latest_version
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "Key"
    value               = "Value"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  instance_refresh {
    strategy = "Rolling"
    preferences {
      min_healthy_percentage = 50
      auto_rollback          = true
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "example" {
  image_id      = "ami-*********"
  instance_type = "i3.large"
}
```

I don't see autoscaling resource have a section with desired configuration in the tf provider [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group). Is this feature missing in Terraform? I do see we have options to enable this using AWS console or AWS cli.

Comment: As far as I have seen, it seems it has been fixed in provider versions >=5.9.0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67446898/instance-not-refreshing-after-launch-configuration-update-terraform

Comment: @MarkoE I don't see this setting defined in any of the versions above 5.9.0.

Comment: @PiyushPatil my question is related to auto rollback during instance refresh. I have instance_refresh block already in the code.

Comment: @wasay It should work the way you have it confgured. Which provider version are you using?

Comment: @MarkoE I was using v4. As you mentioned looks like its fixed in v5. I was looking for a desired_configuration sub-block in instance_refresh block that it was complaining in the error however looks like we don't need it.

Comment: @MarkoE I was able to run the code without any issues starting v5.0.0. Please post an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was fixed in the terraform provider for AWS versions >= 5.9.0. Upgrading the provider version should fix it. The difference was this:

> `auto_rollback` - (Optional) Automatically rollback if instance refresh fails. Defaults to `false`. **This option may only be set to `true` when specifying a `launch_template` or `mixed_instances_policy`.**